# Geberit wall-mounted flush not stopping

Tags: toilet

A Geberit wall-mounted (in-wall?) toilet flush does not stop the water flow automatically if the handle is returned to the original position after flushing. This uses a lot of water and just makes me feel bad about the waste.

I have peeked inside and took the plate out but have not disassembled or taken the other parts out until I know what I'm supposed to look after.

The water stops if the pin is pushed by hand when the front plate is missing but will not return on its own until all the water is gone from the tank.

Anybody has any tips what should make the pressure for the shut-off to work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like the stopper is not adjusted right or needs replacing if old.

Comment: @crip659, would you mind adding an answer, explaining how to adjust the stopper? That was probably the reason, see my answer.

Comment: Do not know that type of toilet.  Most toilet tanks do have the same type of parts, but different designs.  Usually a fill valve that lets water into the tank, a float that stops water flow when the tank is full, and a flapper/stopper that lets the water out to flush.  Usually the float and flapper have some adjustment.  With mention of a short flush, you might have a dual flush setup, a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

After disassembling and assembling the visible parts inside the tank, the operation of the stopper seems fine. This is accidental, however, and I believe it is a consequence of screwing the white push rod only a little bit after switching to the short flush position and back.

So, I assume that previously this rod was screwed too much inside and the push into the flush plate pushed it too far. After that, the water flow was too strong for the mechanism to stop it.

Considering the original problem is solved, I would still like to understand why, in case I need to make adjustments or do it again in the future.

If useful, I will post photos (probably should have done that initially).

Comment: It is _always_ useful to post photos. Please edit them into your original question.